# Make folder from part of a filename, and move corresponding files there - bash scripting

Tags: bash

In have two directories 
finch_data/filteredfirst/aligned
with files

```
firstZBND1X.sam
firstZBND2V.sam
firstZBND3X.sam
firstZBND4X.sam
firstZBND5X.sam
```

and 
finch_data/filteredsec/aligned

```
secZBND1X.sam
secZBND2V.sam
secZBND3X.sam
secZBND4X.sam
secZBND5X.sam
```

I have created a folder 
finch_data/filteredsec/combined
where I have moved all my first*.sam and sec*.sam files.

Now I need to create individual sub-folders using the file manes between the prefix first or sec and .sam. So, folders like:

```
ZBND1X
ZBND2V
ZBND3X
ZBND4X
ZBND5X
```

And then I would need to move the files with those name strings into those corresponding folder.

Anyone with a one line bash to do this?

This is the closer I got from other forums

```
find . -name "*.sam" -exec sh -c 'mkdir "${1%.*}" ; mv "$1" "${1%.*}" ' _ {} \;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it for the files prefixed with `first` (do it similarly for `sec`):

```
#!/bin/bash

prefix=first
for file in ${prefix}*; do
    base="${file%.sam}"
    dir="${base#$prefix}"
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    mv "$file" "$dir"
done
```

It's not a cute oneliner, but it readable. You can write it in one line if you wish, though.

We simply iterate over all files in current directory prefixed with `$prefix`, calculating the `dir` name by stripping the known extension and a known prefix, then creating the directory (if necessary, with `-p` we don't get warnings if dir already exists), and finally moving the file in the target dir. If you wish, you can here also rename the file into something different, perhaps drop the directory name from the filename, etc.

Comment: Or, you could add an outer loop over `for i in finch_data/filtered* ; do ...` and then `prefix=${i##*filtered}`, just to tweak it.

Comment: You could. I just wanted to keep my answer "path-agnostic". :)

Comment: No no, I like your answer just fine the way it is. I just dropped a comment adding a thought to it `:)`